# Android Studio. How after finish instrumented test automate uninstall app?

Tags: android-studio

I have instrumented test. And I run it by gradle:

```
gradlew connectedAndroidTest
```

Test success run and after finish, the application is AUTOMATE unistall from device. OK. It's very good.

But when I start same test by Android Studio (right click over test method and select Run 'testMethod') after test is finish the application is not unistall. How can (by Android Studio) automate uninstall application after finish instrumented test?